# Why are there no compatible JREs in the Execution Environments section even though I've added a JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting an error saying:

```
Unbound classpath container:'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'MyProject'
```

Checking the **Execution Environments**, eclipse seems unable to find any compatible JREs. I can see that **jdk1.8.0_65** is added under **Installed  JREs**.

[image]

[image]

I can temporarily fix the problem by configuring the projects build path to use the JRE explicitly instead of going through the Execution Environments. The problem however will return once I update the project using **Maven**.

Maven is pointing to the variable in the Execution Environments. I can't change the Maven configuration because it's used by several teams (and it's working for them). I need the Execution Environments to detect the JDK.

Note: I've noticed that the file **C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.launching\libraryInfos.xml** is always being generated corrupt. Changing this one so it's similar to my colleagues' doesn't fix the problem.

Environment info:

```
Eclipse - Mars
Windows 7 (x64)
Apache Maven 3.2.5
```

**Note: I've looked at other similar questions on this site but none have been able to answer my question. Their solution is to simply add the JDK under Installed JREs, but in my case that is already done**

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Execution Environments preference page? What does it show as compatible environments and what is checked as the preferred option for JavaSE-1.8?

Comment: Have you tried Maven -> Update project description?

Comment: @ChrisGerken Yes, but that one will point the project towards the Execution Environment variable which in turn point to no JDK.

Comment: @ChrisGerken based on the screenshot, that won't help. The issue isn't that Maven isn't detecting the environment correctly, it's the environment-to-JDK mapping.

Comment: @Adam can you post a screenshot of the "Installed JREs" page as well? It's bizarre that your JDK is not shown under the JavaSE-1.8 section

Comment: @ChrisGerken Added the screenshot. I can't make any sense of this, can't find anyone online who's had the same problem.

Comment: Are you adding the JDK directly or the JRE that lives in the jre/ directory of the JDK?

Comment: @Powerlord I'm adding the JDK root folder **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65**

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

Happens when JAVA_HOME in your system settings is set to a different directory than the VM running eclipse.

Either remove JAVA_HOME or add/change the -vm setting in eclipse.ini to match it.

Comment: That was helpful! And if you want to keep your JAVA_HOME you could create a batch file which modifies this variable and launches eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the **Remove** button to remove the Installed JRE (jdk1.8.0_65) you have.
2. Use the **Add...** button to add the JDK back (making sure to select the *root* of the JDK installation, not any folder contained in the JDK).
3. Close Preferences again, then re-open. At that point you should see the JDK listed on the Execution Environments prefs page, and your project should build.

Comment: Eclipse won't let me close the **Preferences dialog** or navigate away from **Installed JREs** unless I have one JDK/JRE added.

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't help.